# git subtree push missing commits

Tags: git, github

Im working on a project where directory is separated into **/src** and **/dist** directories

```
subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages
```

However, master branch have 13 commits and gh-pages brunch 11 (missing two in between)

I tried to remove `gh-pages` branch and push again, but nothing helps. It's still missing 2 commits (not recent once, some in between history log)

Full command to update github is like this

```
git add . && git commit -m "commit name" && git push origin master && git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages
```

Comment: the 2 "missing" commits may contain changes only that did not affect any files in /dist

Comment: @gizzmole You are perfectly correct. Thanks for the info